# There is already an object named 'Id' in the database. Could not create constraint or index

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, migration, database-migration

im using EF core 3.1 and trying to Update-Database after adding migration, but im getting this error "There is already an object named 'Id' in the database.
Could not create constraint or index"
this is my first Update-Database and nothing is in my database, in my migration i have some DbSets and some configuration in OnModelcreating for columns, i dont know why im getting this error
can smb help me ? : )

Comment: Could you share your model ,dbcontext and migration Please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could find what is the problem, i used HasName method of fluent api in dbcontext class, and that was making this error, I removed it and now its ok